# ASP.NET Core 1.0 Mocking

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, asp.net-core, moq, asp.net-core-1.0

I followed this [ASP.NET Core 1.0: hints to get started](http://blog.markvincze.com/getting-started-with-asp-net-core-1-0-tips-and-tricks/) tutorial and others trying to get some mocking working in my ASP.NET Core MVC project. But I only get this:

```
 Package moq.netcore 4.4.0-beta8 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package moq.netcore 4.4.0-beta8 supports:
  - dotnet (.NETPlatform,Version=v5.0)
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - sl5 (Silverlight,Version=v5.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
```

Is there any solution so far?

My project.json:

```
 {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "APP.Portal": "1.0.0-*",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "moq.netcore": "4.4.0-beta8"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My NuGet.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have this working fine, can you post your package.json?

Comment: '{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "App.Portal": "1.0.0-*",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "moq.netcore": "4.4.0-beta8"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
' This is my project.json

Comment: And: NuGet.config '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <packageSources>
            <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v3/index.json" />
            <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        </packageSources>
    </configuration>'

Comment: Can you edit your question and add it please, not readable via the comments section :)

Comment: Compared with mine I am using the package, "Moq": "4.6.25-alpha" but this also requires "system.diagnostics.tracesource": "4.0.0". I will try updating my solution. Just noticed you are using a different feed too. I don't use myget as that caused me problems and compatibility issues.

Comment: When I try yours I got:   Unable to resolve 'moq.netcore (>= 4.6.25-alpha)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.

Comment: Looks like the feed you are using can't find it, try adding https://www.nuget.org/api/v2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try adding an import for a supported framework.

Something like:

```
"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "dnxcore50",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    }
  }
}
}
```

**EDIT:** I found this post useful for understanding frameworks and imports in .net core - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/

Comment: But is this import cheating like it feels?

Comment: @AnjaHirschmüller yes does feel like cheating I would suggest attempting to resolve the reference via the source I suggested. This is so that you don't need to add the imports. Have a look at https://github.com/OnamChilwan/AspCore-1.0.

Comment: I believe these imports only reference earlier versions of .net core. [More Info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/) 

So I would say no, it's not cheating unless you're referencing the old .Net frameworks. This just allows you to to run dependencies that haven't been updated yet.

I am quite new to this though, so I could be completely off the mark.